# jQuery and array of objects

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    output = "";

    $.ajax({

        url: 'getevents.php',

        data: { ufirstname: 'ufirstname' },

        type: 'post',

        success: function (output) {

            alert(output);

            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            events: output
            });
        }
    });





});
```

I have code like this and if I copy the text verbatim out of my alert box and replace

```
events: output
```

with

```
events: [{ id: 1, title: 'Birthday', start: new Date(1355011200*1000), end: new Date(1355011200*1000), allDay: true, url: 'http://www.yahoo.com/'},{ id: 2, title: 'Birthday Hangover', start: new Date(1355097600*1000), end: new Date(1355097600*1000), allDay: false, url: 'http://www.yahoo.com'},{ id: 3, title: 'Sepotomus Maximus Christmas', start: new Date(1356393600*1000), end: new Date(1356393600*1000), allDay: false, url: 'http://www.yahoo.com/'},]
```

Everything works just fine. What can I do to fix this problem? I though that using `events: output` would place the text in that location but it does not seem to be working.

Thank you all kindly in advance for any comments or answers!

Comment: try setting `dataType:'json` in AJAX. Also plugin has option to use URL as event source and will do the AJAX for you

Comment: Using a URL for the events was actually the solution here. There is a very specific format that the Arshaw Fullcalendar is needing that I will be posting on this thread.

Answer (score 3):

Since you haven't given us much information, i'm going to take a shot in the dark and say that the browser is interpreting the json as text. So add a `dataType` property to the ajax call so that jQuery can parse the return as json.

```
$.ajax({

    url: 'getevents.php',
    data: { ufirstname: 'ufirstname' },
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json' 
    ......
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting that string in your alertbox.. You need to use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse the string into a javascript Object

change

```
events: output
```

to

```
events: JSON.parse(output)
```

According to the [documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/)

> An "event source" is anything that provides FullCalendar with data about events. It can be a simple array, an event-generating function that you define, a URL to a json feed, or a Google Calendar feed.
>
> Since version 1.5, Event Objects can have "options" associated with them. However, before you can start specifying options, you must write an Event Object in its extended form. It must be a traditional JavaScript object with properties.

Also your json string has an extra comma at the end

Comment: if you provide dataType:'JSON' jQuery will parse it automatically

Comment: @popnoodles Yes I know.  They both will do the same thing

Answer (score -1):

```
    $year = date('Y');
$month = date('m');

echo json_encode(array(

    array(
        'id' => 111,
        'title' => "Event1",
        'start' => "$year-$month-10",
        'url' => "http://yahoo.com/"
    ),

    array(
        'id' => 222,
        'title' => "Event2",
        'start' => "$year-$month-20",
        'end' => "$year-$month-22",
        'url' => "http://yahoo.com/"
    )

));
```

The program actually wants this very specific format of json_encode or it does not work. I only figured this out by reading through all of these replies.